# using split() with subprocess.check_output()

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, subprocess

I'm trying to take the output of `upower -d` (shell command) and split it into a long list using .split() so it can be searched.

When I do

```
import subprocess
dump = subprocess.check_output(["upower", "-d"])
print(dump.split())
```

it will print the output in list form as expected except every element in the list is preceded with a "b" (not inside the string).

When I do the same in python 2.7 it gives me the output I expect but I would like it to be in python 3.

Comment: Could you post the output in python3 and python2 ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`b""` is a `bytes` literal in Python. In Python 2.7, `""` is also a bytestring. `print(your_list)` prints representations (`repr`) of each item that is why you see `b""` in Python 3 but not in Python 2.

`subprocess.check_output()` returns bytes in both Python 2 and 3 unless `universal_newlines=True` specified in Python 3 that uses `locale.getpreferredencoding(False)` to decode the bytes.

```
from subprocess import check_output

output = check_output(["upower", "-d"], universal_newlines=True)
print(output.split())
```

Comment: +1 Better answer that mine. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: Thanks for this, it solved the issue. Excuse the args not being in a list. I wrote the question at like 3 am. I was torn between putting "upower -d".split() and ["upower", "-d"].

Answer (score 3):

You can also use dump.decode().split().

Decode will convert bytes into str, and then you can use split as before.